# codeigniter ajax/json change div color according to status in database

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter

I have a ajax beginner question please:

I have a database table with companies: id, company_name, select_button, status

When user clicks the select_button on a company-row, the status changes to 2 which works fine. However, there is also a progress bar for each company-row and when status is 2 for the company-row I wish that the progressbar for that company-row shall change color from green (status 1) to red (status 2). Here is one of the unsuccessful ways I tried to do it:

Model (name: get_status) - get status for each company row:

```
public function get_status(){
    $this->db->select('status')
            ->from('companies');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller (name: status) - receive status for each company row and send it to view via json:

```
public function status(){
    $output = $this->platform_model->get_status();
    return json_encode($output);
}
```

View (name: platform_view) - Receive controller result and do the logic for changing the progress-bar color according to status being either 2 or 1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('home/status');?>',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(output){
                if(output === 2){
                  $('.ui-progressbar-value').css('background', 'red');  
                }else{
                    $('.ui-progressbar-value').css('background', 'green');
                }

            }
         });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should `echo` the json string, and not return it from controller.

Secondly, you need to understand that your AJAX will receive a JSON object, not a single value.

Your code should be (controller) :

```
public function status(){
$output = $this->platform_model->get_status();
echo json_encode($output);
}
```

and ajax :

```
    $ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('home/status');?>',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(output){
           // Sure you need the ===? Sometimes it does problems 
            if(output.status == "2" ){ 

              $('.ui-progressbar-value').css('background', 'red');  
            }else{
                $('.ui-progressbar-value').css('background', 'green');
            }

        }
     }).fail(function(){
             console.log("Error getting data from server");
   });
```